# io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: java.io.InterruptedIOException

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit

I use `RxJava` and `Retrofit` to make network requests, but I occasionally receive error feedback. At `ApiManager.java:216` is my add method of common parameters.

Error message:

```
io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: java.io.InterruptedIOException
    at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:349)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableUnsubscribeOn$UnsubscribeObserver.onError(ObservableUnsubscribeOn.java:67)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable$BodyObserver.onError(BodyObservable.java:72)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:55)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10955)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10955)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableUnsubscribeOn.subscribeActual(ObservableUnsubscribeOn.java:32)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10955)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
    at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:452)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:61)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:52)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
Caused by: java.io.InterruptedIOException
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.waitForIo(Http2Stream.java:579)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeResponseHeaders(Http2Stream.java:143)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http2Codec.java:120)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:75)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at com.fc.happygo.net.ApiManager$SignInterceptor.intercept(ApiManager.java:216)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:69)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:41)
    ... 14 more
```

ApiManager.java:216:

```
public static class SignInterceptor implements Interceptor {

        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();
          //...add sign parameter
            return chain.proceed(request);//line: 216
        }
    }
```

At `OkHttpClient`:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new SignInterceptor());
```

The above is the relevant code. Error messages only appear occasionally. It never happened during the test. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Suggested reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/docs/What's-different-in-2.0.md#error-handling

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, the error is occurring because there is no `Subscriber` registered to deliver the error to and no global one set through `RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler()`

However, the crux of the issue looks to be because

```
okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.waitForIo(Http2Stream.java:579)
```

is waiting and interrupted when the Rx stream making the API call is disposed of.

From the stack trace it looks like you are running into this:

```
  /**
   * Removes and returns the stream's received response headers, blocking if necessary until headers
   * have been received. If the returned list contains multiple blocks of headers the blocks will be
   * delimited by 'null'.
   */
  public synchronized List<Header> takeResponseHeaders() throws IOException {
```

so what you need to do is make sure that when you unsubscribe from your Rx stream making this API call, you are first cancelling that connection to the stream (which, and I'm just guessing here, is open or contains multiple blocks of headers ). This should take care of the continued waiting and resolve the crash.

However, simply adding the plugin for a global handler will be a quick fix since it will stop the crash and allow you to recover.